# Which key action does the nexus phone fire when back button pressed?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, back-button, google-nexus

I'm wondering which KeyEvent action is called when a user presses the little upside-down triangle in nexus phone when soft keyboard is open.

In normal mode Nexus looks like this and the normal code works fine:
[Nexus without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2TXE.png)

But when keyboard pops up it looks like this and the code won't work:

[Nexus with keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbshZ.png)

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {}

Comment: @JCDecary I used onKeyDown(), when the keyboard is hidden and the triangle points to the left I get the the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK but in keyboard presence I don't know what it fires up!

Comment: maybe this will help you : http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html .Im not sur what you want

Answer (score 2):

For android API up to 5:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
}
```

For android before API 5 you must use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Please refer to [How to handle back button in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity)

**EDIT:**

This methods works only if the keyboard is hidden..

according with this answer: [Detect back key press - When keyboard is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718437/detect-back-key-press-when-keyboard-is-open)

The best action to be implement is dispatchKeyEventPreIme.
An example is:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchKeyEventPreIme(" + event + ")");
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            KeyEvent.DispatcherState state = getKeyDispatcherState();
            if (state != null) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    state.startTracking(event, this);
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && !event.isCanceled() && state.isTracking(event)) {
                    mActivity.onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }
```

**Where mActivity is your activity class (this).**

Comment: As I said, in emulator I'm Using when keyboard is present this code won't work!

Comment: The debugger enter in that code when keyboard is opened or the action doesn't fire?

Comment: I added 2 photos and updated the question, have a look.

Comment: This way I need to override my root layout view and I prefer not to do so.